# Nuxt Increasing Memory Usage in Console

Tags: npm, nuxtjs

I am building a project in nuxtjs. Whenever I run `npm run dev` at last it shows memory usage and the memory usage is increasing with the size of my project. Can anyone explain me about this memory usage? Is it going to take that amount of memory in production mode? I was also thinking if my application traffic grows is it going to take more memory?

[image]

Another problem I am facing is The "loose" option problem is not going away. when I try to build my project locally for production it doesn't build the project. The "loose" option warning prints like a loop in the console and never ends.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `npm run build` or `npm run prod` will run npm only once and then exit, no longer taking CPU or memory. You can also just try that yourself with a small example project. The `loose` option I cannot help with, sorry.

Comment: Isn't it going to allocate that amount of memory in the ram?

Comment: Yes but only once when generating the files and then npm exists. npm is only needed to generate the files that are sent to the browser. It is not running in the background in production.

Comment: One last question in my mind If my website traffic grows is it going to affect memory usage? If I have hosting with 4gb of ram and traffic grows is it going to crash at that time when there will be huge traffic?

Comment: Not by npm, no. npm generates files. Then npm is no longer running. After that the files are sent to all browsers. It only takes ram to read the file to transfer the files to every browser. But that is also the case for every solution that sends websites to the browser.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think I have now clear understanding of this.

Comment: You're welcome. If you use up 4gb of RAM to deliver the website you have a very successful one anyway and you will hopefully be able to afford the upgrade for more RAM.

Comment: Yes basically i used it as a example